# c# ASP.Net WebForm E-Commerce Payment Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, e-commerce

For the purpose of learning ASP.Net i have created an ASP.Net website which its theme is a small local hotel company has setup a website where people can become members on the website view the available hotels to make a reservation.

I've come to the point where i need to integrate some sort of payment system onto my website, i've done some research and if i want the user to pay via credit card i would need to setup SSL etc. Something which at this stage (Beginner) i'm not looking to learn.

However i think i can setup a paypal system, i'm just not sure how and if its possible to do the things i want.

1.Make Payment For Specific hotel, price is based on the users chosen checkin and checkout date. My database has a price per night column in the room table.
2. Store Payment History would i need to setup an SQL table for this or is this done by paypal.
3.^ Relating to previous, if user pays i need the option to allow them to cancel there reservation which then there paypal payment also needs to be cancelled.
4. If they reserve a room or cancel a reservation email needs to be sent.

If you know of a tutorial which covers this basic e-commerce for c# asp.net web form and utilities a paypal system let me know aswell!.

Comment: Top two results for *"asp.net paypal"* google search: [Use of the PayPal payment system in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET) and [Introduction to PayPal for C# - ASP.NET developers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers). Haven't read them, but both have really good ratings.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that "becoming a member" is not a pre-requisite to renting a room.

The biggest problem with PayPal/ASPNET is the fact that ASPNET only allows a single form tag per page. Here's a solution to that (disclaimer: my own blog posts):

http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal (three posts)

You should also utilize IPN for payment verification - see the [PayPal documentation](https://www.paypal.com/ipn). Users do not need to be PayPal members to use their credit cards securely. You will need to set up a secure certificate on your server however.

As for cancellations, they can notify the hotel owner who can then use the PayPal admin to apply the refund - very straightforward. This is a manual process; keep it simple.

Regarding payment history, PayPal does this but it not a satisfactory way of doing it. Set up your own orders table (with a 'confirmed' field) and update the confirmed field when the payment is authorized (via IPN). You'll also update this in the event of a cancellation.

Check out Rick Strahl's [article](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0509061).

Comment: Ty, this is very informative. However i don't have a server atm, so how can i setup a secure certificate? Is it possible to setup paypal payment without?

Comment: Yes, you do need a secure cert to send the transactions over https://. Consult with your host, it really should not be a problem :-)

Comment: I don't have a host, "For the purpose of learning ASP.Net i have created an ASP.Net website" This is not a "real website".

Comment: Then you don't need a cert. And you can use the PayPal sandbox :-)

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf